# How do I sign out from Superuser?

Tags: support, logout

I'm looking for the sign out button here.  Where is it?  I can't add any more detail. 
It says I need more in this segment but I don't have anymore detail.

Answer (score 5):

It's under the StackExchange menu on the top left of the browser window:

[image]

Comment: Thank you cody codes.

Answer (score 4):

Since recent UI changes, the 'Log Out' button is now located in the 'speech bubble shaped hamburger' in the top right.

[image]

Comment: This took waaaaaaay to long to find. UX overhaul needed methinks.